# How to create hyperlink for the column values from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: excel

The task Ids from sheet 1 in the below screenshot are used in the sheet 2

**Sheet 1**

[image]

**Sheet 2**
Task ids for each employee with hours for every task

[image]

How to create  hyperlink for the task id values entered in the sheet2 , such that a click on the value should traverse to sheet1 which will help me to know which employee is working on what task and how many hours.

Comment: [This VBA-based solution](http://superuser.com/questions/663580/trigger-macro-with-one-click-on-specific-cell) looks like it might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

To access values you use `sheet2!A3` the same works for hyperlinks as well (with some quoting): `=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!A3","see A3")`